# wamp and IIS server simultaneously

Tags: wampserver

hii ,i want to run wamp and IIS both ,but IIS is using port 80 so what shall i do.if I turn off IIS my internet goes off.And i also tried changing port for wamp server in httpd.conf  (listen:8080) but still not working
plzz help me out ,I shall be grateful to u.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set up the same thing recently. There is a registry hack you have to perform to get it to work. Check out this website article for more info. Specifically the section on editing the registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\ListenOnlyList`

For more information see:

> [Setting Both Wamp & IIS on 80 Port (no need of 81 now) (archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20101120054823/http://beyondweblogs.com/post/Setting-Both-Wamp-IIS-on-80-Port-%28no-need-of-81-now%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Having this same problem. I've configured WAMP to listen to 8080. It works for the the index of localhost, but when I try to navigate to my Wordpress folder it switches to port 80 and IIS catches it. Thanks